# Ionic 2 slider is undefined and options dont work

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i have a huge problem with my ionic 2 slider (ion-slide).

At first my code :)

Typescript:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
export class WorkoutStartPage {
    @ViewChild('mySlider') mySlider:Slides;

    public itemList: Array<any>;
    public _options: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public appData: AppData) {
      console.log(this.mySlider); // undefinded

      this._options = {
          slidesPerView:2.5,
          pager: false,
          speed: 800,
          autoplay: 5000,
          effect: 'fade',
          fade: {
              crossFade: true
          },
          loop: 'true',
          autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
      }

    }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.appData.getItems().then((items:Array<any>) => {
        this.itemList = items;
    });
  }
}
```

My template:

```
<ion-content id="page-workout-start">

    <div class="c-headline c-headline--has-padding animated fadeIn">Title</div>

    <div *ngIf="itemList">
        <ion-slides class="c-item-list-slider animated fadeIn" [options]="_options" mySlider>
            <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of itemList">
                <div class="header-with-background">
                    <img src="{{item.image}}">
                    <div class="img-overlay animated fadeIn">
                        <h1 [innerHTML]="item.title"></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>{{item.infos}}</p>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

**My Problem**

The ion slider dont take the _options and "`@ViewChild('mySlider') mySlider:Slides;`" is also undefinded.

Does someome have a idea why this dont work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Angular template variable is declared like `#variableName`, so you need to change your `mySlider` to `#mySlider` on `ion-slides` tag.

Also property `this.mySlider` should be assigned a `#mySlider` value after content init. So it is undefined in constructor in any case.

Use `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook to get your slider in component.

Also if you use just released Ionic 2 then you should review docs as [Slides API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/) changed cardinally